# How to deactivate the default stop words feature for sklearn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to get the tf-idf values for Japanese words.
The problem I am having is that sklearn TfidfVectorizer removes some Japanese characters, which I want to keep, as stop words.

The following is the example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = None)

words_list = ["歯","が","痛い"]
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(words_list)
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names() 
print (feature_names)
```

The output is:`['痛い']`

However, I want to keep all those three characters in the list.
I believe TfidfVectorizer removes characters with length of 1 as stop words.
How could I deactivate the default stop words feature and keep all characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the *token_pattern* parameter from `(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b` (default) to `(?u)\\b\\w\\w*\\b`; The default matches token that has two or more word characters (in case you are not familiar with regex, `+` means one or more, so `\\w\\w+` matches word with two or more word characters; `*` on the other hand means zero or more, `\\w\\w*` will thus match word with one or more characters):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w*\\b')
​
words_list = ["歯","が","痛い"]
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(words_list)
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names() 
print(feature_names)
# ['が', '歯', '痛い']
```